# Exchange: Force users to book through meeting planner

Tags: exchange

We've been having some issues with users booking a room directly in that room's calendar, rather than through the meeting planner in Outlook, with the result that they are able to book conflicting meetings.

Does anyone know how we can force them to use the meeting planner, inviting the room as a resource?

Update: It seems that this issue surfaced after we upgraded to Exchange 2013. The direct booking option was deprecated in Exchange 2013, but old resources could still be booked through this option.

Comment: This is a human problem.  The simplest method meditation, would be to not honor meetings, not scheduled with the meeting planner.  *Software can't fix a human behavior like this.*

Comment: While it is a human problem, there should be a software solution to the issue.

Comment: not all human behavior problems can be solved by software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using the information from this blog post: https://www.weavweb.net/2016/07/21/what-a-mess-exchange-2013-with-direct-booking-and-the-autoaccept-agent/